# Earth Engine Zonal Stats export table error message

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, zonal-statistics

[image]

I am trying to calculate zonal statistics of vegetation indices (Sentinel 2) for each week in 2023 and export the results in a wide table format (.csv). For the specific region, I am using points data.
I receive an error message "Parameter 'delta' is required" when I initiate table export.

```
// Load the shapefile as a feature collection
var region = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-gsehi/assets/2023_BG_traps_Zonal_v3");


// Define the start and end date for 2023
var startDate = '2023-01-01';
var endDate = '2023-12-31';

// Define the time window length as 1 week
var interval = 1;
var intervalUnit = 'week';
var intervalCount = 52;  // Number of weeks in 2023

// Reducer to calculate mean vegetation index
var temporalReducer = ee.Reducer.mean();

// Define spatial reducers for mean, standard deviation, and variance
var spatialReducers = ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  sharedInputs: true
}).combine({
  reducer2: ee.Reducer.variance(),
  sharedInputs: true
});

// Function to calculate NDVI
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

// Load the Sentinel-2 image collection and apply NDVI calculation function
var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                            .filterBounds(region)
                            .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
                            .map(addNDVI);


// Calculate zonal statistics for each week in 2023
var zonalStats = ee.List.sequence(1, intervalCount).map(function(week) {
  var start = ee.Date(startDate).advance(week - 1, intervalUnit);
  var end = ee.Date(startDate).advance(week, intervalUnit);
  
  // Filter the image collection for the current week
  var weeklyImages = sentinel2.filterDate(start, end);
  
  // Reduce the images to get temporal statistics for the week
  var weeklyStat = weeklyImages.reduce(temporalReducer);
  
  // Calculate zonal statistics over the region of interest
  var stats = weeklyStat.reduceRegion({
    reducer: spatialReducers,
    geometry: region,
    scale: 10, // Adjust scale as needed
    maxPixels: 1e9 // Increase maxPixels if necessary
  });
  
  // Set the start date of the week
  stats = stats.set('system:time_start', start);
  
  // Convert to feature and return
  return ee.Feature(null, stats);
});

// Convert the list of zonal statistics to a feature collection
var zonalStatsCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(zonalStats);

// Export the zonal statistics to Google Drive
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: zonalStatsCollection,
  description: 'zonal_stats_2023',
  folder: 'NDVI_2023', // Specify the folder in your Google Drive
  fileFormat: 'CSV' // You can export to other formats as well, e.g., 'CSV', 'GeoJSON', etc.
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this error is not related to the export process, but to the script itself. 'delta' is a parameter for [ee.Date.advance](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-date-advance), and the error message is saying that it is not specified correctly.

On line 41, you treat *week* as a number, but it is actually an ee.Number. Instead of

```
var start = ee.Date(startDate).advance(week - 1, intervalUnit);
```

You should try

```
var start = ee.Date(startDate).advance(ee.Number(week).subtract(1), intervalUnit);
```

See this [closely related question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/467124/image-error-parameter-delta-is-required-googleearthengine).